# Подключении два модуля так чтобы они были на разных портах но работали с одним БД

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Здравствуйте у меня есть идея подключить несколько проектов в одно. Тоесть сделать модули и работать уже с ними. Но проблема в том что эти проекты на разных портах и с разными базами данных и с разным Security. Как с помощью модулей подключить эти все проекты во едино